# Adding multiple series to a chart

Tags: excel, vba, charts

Can anyone help improve my VBA code below?

I'm wanting to create a line diagram using a chart to plot the start and end co-ordinates.

At the moment I have to copy, paste and amend the code for each line.

Any help on how to modify the code to allow for any number of lines would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

```
Sub creatmychart()
    Dim Chart1 As Chart
    Set Chart1 = Charts.Add
    With Chart1
        .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=members!$A2"
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=members!$D$2,members!$F$2"
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = "=members!$E$2,members!$G$2"

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(2).Name = "=members!$A3"
        .SeriesCollection(2).XValues = "=members!$D$3,members!$F$3"
        .SeriesCollection(2).Values = "=members!$E$3,members!$G$3"

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(3).Name = "=members!$A4"
        .SeriesCollection(3).XValues = "=members!$D$4,members!$F$4"
        .SeriesCollection(3).Values = "=members!$E$4,members!$G$4"

        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(4).Name = "=members!$A5"
        .SeriesCollection(4).XValues = "=members!$D$5,members!$F$5"
        .SeriesCollection(4).Values = "=members!$E$5,members!$G$5"

    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a loop.  Try the below (assuming your info goes to up to 11):

```
Sub creatmychart()
Dim Chart1  As Chart
Set Chart1 = Charts.Add

Dim i       As Long
With Chart1
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLines
    For i = 1 To 11
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(i).Name = "=members!$A" & i + 1
        .SeriesCollection(i).XValues = "=members!$D$" & i + 1 & ",members!$F$" & i + 1
        .SeriesCollection(i).Values = "=members!$E$" & i + 1 & ",members!$G$" & i + 1
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Bruce, that works great. Can I link "11" to a cell value?

Comment: @Anthony of course! Assuming `A1` has the number you want to go to just for `For I = 1 to Range("A1").Value`

Comment: (@Anthony - if this works for you as the Answer, do you mind marking it as such by clicking the check mark left of the post, below the down arrow? It will mark your questions as Answered. Thanks!)